# Validate Azure Resource Group option disappears from menu in VS2017

Tags: azure

1. Create Azure Resource Group (from Function App dedicated template) project in VS2017 Enterprise Version 15.6.7
2. Create new dev-azuredeploy-parameters.json file
3. Add resources, params, etc. to azuredeploy.json file
4. Right-click project, select "Validate". ARM template is validated.
5. Close solution, close VS, open VS, open solution
6. Make changes to azuredeploy.json
7. Right-click project to validate

**Expected behavior**: Validate option is available
**Actual behavior**: Validate option is missing

Comment: This issue has been reported by another user

Comment: not understanding why people would downgrade this. But this question lead me to the answer below, which worked for me! Could you mark @acousticplanet answer as the solution?

Answer (score 9):

Appears to be in bug in VS2017.

Workaround: Unload the project, reload the project. The Validate menu option should now be visible.